# Почему не срабатывает регулярное выражение после считывания текста из файла в строку?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть файл с текстом, к примеру **1.txt**
Текст в файле ---> "`фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.`"

```
//Считываю текст в переменную  

    String textFromFile = Files.readString(Path.of("1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);  

//Вывожу текст в консоль чтобы убедиться что все считано  

    System.out.println(textFromFile); // фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.

//Проверяю регулярным выражением вхождение подстроки  

    System.out.println(textFromFile.matches("(.*) в (.*)")); // false
    System.out.println(textFromFile.matches("(.*)\\sв\\s(.*)")); // false
    System.out.println(textFromFile.matches(".*в.*")); // false

//Подставляю вместо переменной непосредственно сам текст  

    System.out.println("фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.".matches("(.*) в (.*)")); // true
    System.out.println("фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.".matches("(.*)\\sв\\s(.*)")); // true
    System.out.println("фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.".matches(".*в.*")); // true
```

Почему проверка переменной на вхождение подстроки дает false?
Куда смотреть, где почитать, что упускаю?

Comment: А вот так - `System.out.println(textFromFile.trim().matches("(.*) в (.*)"));`?

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, в конце строки стоит символ перевода строки `\n` или `\r\n`.

Метод `Files::readString` считывает весь файл целиком в одну строку, а метод `String::matches` точно так же сравнивает с паттерном всю строку, при этом по умолчанию символ `.` не включает символы окончания строк.

Нужно либо обрезать пробельные символы при помощи `String::trim`, либо убрать их при помощи `String::replaceAll`, либо изменить паттерн, чтобы включить режим `Pattern.DOTALL`, например, при помощи флажка `(?s)`:

```java
System.out.println("'" + textFromFile + "'");
// -> 'фффффффф в ррррр ллллл вавава на.
// -> '
System.out.println(textFromFile.trim().matches("(.*) в (.*)")); 
// -> true
System.out.println(textFromFile.replaceAll("\\R", "").matches("(.*) в (.*)")); 
// -> true
System.out.println(textFromFile.matches("(?s)(.*) в (.*)")); 
// -> true
```